# Look up from a dictionary to fill pandas DataFrame with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, hashmap

I have a dictionary that's something like this.

```
d = {
     "p1": ["$0.00", nan, "$25.00"],
     "p2": ["$30.25", nan, "$12.25"],
     "p3": ["$0.00"],
     "p4": [nan, "$15.00"]
    }
```

I'd like to look up values from the dictionary and assign them to a column in pandas DataFrame. The DataFrame is something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'name': ["p1","p2","p3","p4"],
                   'val': [np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan] 
                   })
```

Assignment:

```
def fun(name):
 
    # look up from dict

    # apply condition

    return 

df['val'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['name']), axis=1)
```

For the assignment, the condition is to find the largest value from the dictionary, if length of the value pair > 0, i.e there is more than 1 element in the list. Note, the elements are stored as strings. So, need the function needs to convert them to float type.

Expected output:

[image: eo]

Answer (score 1):

First rework your dictionary to keep the "highest" value with a custom `key`. Then perform a simple `map`:

```
d2 = {k: max((e for e in v if pd.notna(e)),
             key=lambda x: float(x.strip('$')) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
      for k,v in d.items()}
# {'p1': '$25.00', 'p2': '$30.25', 'p3': '$0.00', 'p4': '$15.00'}

df['val'] = df['name'].map(d2)
```

output:

```
  name     val
0   p1  $25.00
1   p2  $30.25
2   p3   $0.00
3   p4  $15.00
```

Comment: Found an edge case. When the first value in the list is `nan`, it the dictionary selects `nan` as the max value. I updated the dict with the case to handle.

Comment: @kms easy fix, just get rid of the NaNs, `map` fills with NaNs by default when no match is found ;)